# Can we send user info from client-side to the server-side, safely?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angular, security

I want to get user info like (monitor size, IP, etc) on the browser/client-side and send them to the server-side,
but the problem is that can some user change our front-end code and prevent his user info to be sent to the server?

another example is that I want to calculate some information for a user and then send them to the server but I won't receive cheat information to the server from manipulated data in the browser side by a tricky user.

"so, is it possible for users to change our written code in the front-end to send their desire information to the server instead of calculated progress data which has performed by the real code?"

Comment: It’s ultimately all arbitrary data sent through an open protocol, anyone can send anything to you at any time. None of it is ultimately trustable.

Comment: Unfortunately No,.  The only thing you can do is make it harder for them using obfuscation.  Possible the hardest option for user to crack might be WASM, but even then somebody who was really really determined to cheat, and had the knowledge could get by it.